# Actionscript, does a faster hashing method exist than MD5?

Tags: actionscript-3, hash, actionscript, md5

I am using as3corelib's MD5 has function from adobe.

I am hashing a 3mb file, this is taking around 6 seconds on decent hardware.

I must find a much faster way of creating a hash.

Am I correct in assuming that its slow because its running inside the actionscript virtual machine?

Do any ways exist to speed it up?

I am really looking for minimum possible security and so if some more simple hash method exists and was faster this may be a solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use BloodyCrypto http://blooddy.by
It has other types available too.

Comment: Thanks. Thats great.

Comment: Following further testing, the Blooddy library was at least 5 x faster than the adobe version.